# Search through a multi-dimensional array with multiple value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. After doing some condition my resulting array is as shown below.

```
//filtered aray
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => -1129794.96
            [member_id] => 1
            [type] => InternalTransfers
            [transaction_type] => Accumulation
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => 1129794.96
            [member_id] => 1
            [type] => PensionsRolledBack
            [transaction_type] => Accumulation
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => -1129794.96
            [member_id] => 1
            [type] => PensionsRolledBack
            [transaction_type] => Pension
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => 1129794.96
            [member_id] => 2
            [type] => InternalTransfers
            [transaction_type] => Accumulation
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => -1129794.96
            [member_id] => 2
            [type] => PensionCommencement
            [transaction_type] => Accumulation
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => 1129794.96
            [member_id] => 2
            [type] => PensionCommencement
            [transaction_type] => Pension
        )

)
```

My job is to remove any offsetting transactions. For example: If one member's accumulation has a positive and negative, then remove them.

By using this resultant array, I need to filter based on `member_id`, `transaction_type` and `transaction_amount`. (it may be positive or negative).
If `member_id` and `transaction_type` are same then I need to remove the offsetting transaction.

After removal, the resulting array must look like this:

```
Array
(
   [23] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => -1129794.96
            [member_id] => 1
            [type] => PensionsRolledBack
            [transaction_type] => Pension
        )

   [56] => Array
       (
           [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
           [Description] => Pension Reversion
           [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
           [transaction_amount] => 1129794.96
           [member_id] => 2
           [type] => PensionCommencement
          [transaction_type] => Pension
     )
)
```

MY CODE

```
$total = $array;
    array_walk($array, function($value) use(&$total){
         $result = $this->multiSearch($total, array('transaction_type' =>$value['transaction_type'], 'smsf_actuarial_form_member_id' => $value['smsf_actuarial_form_member_id'], 'transaction_amount' => $value['transaction_amount']));
         pr($result);exit;
    });
public function multiSearch(array $array, array $pairs) {
    $found = array();
    foreach ($array as $aKey => $aVal) {
        $coincidences = 0;
        foreach ($pairs as $pKey => $pVal) {
            if (array_key_exists($pKey, $aVal)) {
                if(is_double($aVal[$pKey]) && is_double($pVal) && abs($aVal[$pKey]) == abs($pVal)){
                    $coincidences++;
                } else if($aVal[$pKey] == $pVal){                        
                    $coincidences++;
                } 
            }
        }
        if ($coincidences == count($pairs)) {
            $found[$aKey] = $aVal;
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

I have filtered based on member_id, transaction_type and transaction_amount.

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => -1129794.96
            [smsf_actuarial_form_member_id] => 1
            [type] => InternalTransfers
            [transaction_type] => Accumulation
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [OriginEventId] => 0152c945-e15b-48f9-8a0e-e4b9eace4731
            [Description] => Pension Reversion
            [transaction_date] => 2014-10-30T00:00:00
            [transaction_amount] => 1129794.96
            [smsf_actuarial_form_member_id] => 1
            [type] => PensionsRolledBack
            [transaction_type] => Accumulation
        )
```

If with same member id, transaction type and transaction amount with both positive and negative, then I need to delete it.

**Flow**

1. Filter an array with member_id, transaction_type and transaction_amount(Both positive and negative).
2. If a resulting array has both positive and negative, then unlink that both array with filtered array.

Condition works dynamically.

[PLEASE VIEW CODE HERE](https://eval.in/687864)

Comment: I can't see the problem (am I missing something?), just loop through the values using a foreach and use an if

Comment: Did you ever heard of [`array_filter(function($input){ ... }, $array);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) ?

Answer (score 2):

To remove elements in an array, use the [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (
                $value['member_id'] === $v['member_id'] &&
                $value['transaction_type'] === $v['transaction_type'] &&
                $value['transaction_amount'] === -$v['transaction_amount']
            ) {
                unset($array[$key], $array[$k]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i had 4 resulting array with 2 positive and 2 negative is it work?